# What do Ftg Atk and Sick Atk upgrade stats do in Rune Factory 4?

Tags: rune-factory-4

Both fatigue and cold status effects affect RP of your character. But what happen when you add these attacks to your weapon? Because enemies don't have RP.

[One guy on gamefaqs](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/635388-rune-factory-4/68233328) said it will at least help you level Resist Fatigue and Resist Cold stats if you manage to inflict them to monsters.